# PhoneGap + Leaflet + Jquery Mobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, leaflet

I am trying to get Leaflet maps working with a PhoneGap app and the map will not render full screen and am not sure why.

**index.html**

```
<div data-role="content" id="map" style="width:100%;height:70%;position:absolute;">
  var map = new Map();
  var $map = $('#map');
  $map.height( $(window).height() - $map.offset().top );
```

**maps.js**

```
function Map() {
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            }).addTo(map);

L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map)
.bindPopup('A pretty CSS3 popup. <br> Easily customizable.')
.openPopup();
}
```

But I keep getting this where the map is off to the far right and wont load anywhere else:

http://postimage.org/image/r0e49wgt5/

(Wont let me post images with reputation)

**Update**

The map will load if I turn the app Landscape but if I stay in portrait the map will be grey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `map.invalidateSize();` after displaying map.